# ammend sys.path but still can't find a module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with an API which has the following code it it:

```
# aardvark_py.py
import os
import sys
try:
    import aardvark as api
except ImportError, ex1:
    import imp, platform
    ext = platform.system() in ('Windows', 'Microsoft') and '.dll' or '.so'
    try:
        api = imp.load_dynamic('aardvark', 'aardvark' + ext)
    except ImportError, ex2:
        import_err_msg  = 'Error importing aardvark%s\n' % ext
        import_err_msg += '  Architecture of aardvark%s may be wrong\n' % ext
        import_err_msg += '%s\n%s' % (ex1, ex2)
        raise ImportError(import_err_msg)
```

Needless to say that I can't modify this code.

My problem is in this line of code:

```
api = imp.load_dynamic('aardvark', 'aardvark' + ext)
```

The second argument species a path to the `.dll`, i.e. it is set to `aarvark.dll`, which is in the same location where `aardvark_py.py` is located. I import this module, `aardvark_py` into my code. My code is not located in the same location as `aardvark_py.py` and `aardvark.dll`. However when I do an import it fails. It raises an exception. It looks like it doesn't know where `.dll` is located, but I can't figure out why. Here is the error I'm getting

```
"path\to\aardvark_py.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(import_err_msg)
ImportError: Error importing aardvark.dll
  Architecture of aardvark.dll may be wrong
No module named aardvark
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is approximate directory layout:

```
project_dir -
     |
     |- 3rdparty
     |    |
     |    |-aardvark
     |         |
     |         |-aarvark_py.py
     |         |-aardvark.dll     
     |
     |
     |-tools
         |
         |-mycode.py
```

`mycode.py` does contain code to ammend `sys.path`

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), '..', '3rdparty', 'aardvark')
```

Comment: @solarc: It looks like the code is using the old pre-2.5 kludge for conditional expressions, where people would do `condition and true_case or false_case`.

Comment: @user2357112 right, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in 32-bit python 2.7. I installed 64-bit python 2.7 and now it works.